# Get pods on nodes with certain label

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

This is an extension to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231880/kubernetes-api-gets-pods-on-specific-nodes) - how can I get the list pods running on nodes with a certain label?

I am trying to find the pods in a specific zone (failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone)

Answer (score 6):

You can get all nodes' name with the label you want using `for` command and list the pods within theses nodes:

Example:

```
for node in $(kubectl get nodes -l failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-central1-c -ojsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'); do kubectl get pods -A -owide --field-selector spec.nodeName=$node; done
```

The command will list all pods with label `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-central1-c` and then list the pods.

Comment: Wasn't expecting something O(Nodes * Pods), but if this is the best possible then will have to take it..

Answer (score 0):

To avoid iterating over each node, you can instead include the node name on the pods output, then filter against the node list:

```bash
nodes=$(kubectl get nodes -l failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-central1-c \
    -o go-template --template='{{range .items}}{{printf "%s\n" .metadata.name}}{{end}}' \
    | paste -sd '|')
if ! [ -z "$nodes" ]; then
    kubectl get pods -A \
        -o go-template --template='{{range .items}}{{printf "%s|%s\n" .spec.nodeName .metadata.name}}{{end}}' \
        | grep -P "^$nodes"
fi
```