# Get Pods from a Particular node using k8s rest api

Tags: go, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod, client-go

is there any k8s rest api endpoint to fetch all the pods and its details of a paricular node.
I use minikube and started a proxy using `kubectl proxy --port=7070 &`.
We have endpoints like  `GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace-name}/pods`. Do we have any similar endpoint to access pods belonging to a specific node? I dont want to use kubectl commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `client-go` library to talk to the `API server`. Here is an example.

```
import (
     "github.com/golang/glog"

     "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
     "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/fields"
     "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
     "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
     "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)
func main() {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "")
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln(err)
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln(err)
    }
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I dont want to use kubectl commands.

`kubectl` is a `REST` client for k8s `API server`. If you don't want to use it - you will need to perform the same requests manually.

There is no "legal" way to get information from k8s cluster without talking to `API Server`. The `API Server` is the only source of truth and all controllers are using the `API Server` to perform required changes. So, probably, you should rely on the information provided by the `API Server`.

You can use `kubectl` to get pods for specific node by:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<node>
```

check this out: [Kubernetes API - gets Pods on specific nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231880/kubernetes-api-gets-pods-on-specific-nodes)

You can also do that without using `kubectl` - read this: [The Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/)

Comment: if you must use REST APIs you can pass `-v9` to  the above command to make it verbose. v9 prints the HTTP requests as proper `curl` requests that you can copy and try.